# Alternativas ao Microsoft Lightswitch

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida em .NET usando uma extensão da Microsoft chamada Lightswitch que infelizmente não consigo abrir nem correr. No entanto, ele se tornou obsoleto.

Quais são as melhores alternativas de forma a implementar de raiz uma nova aplicação semelhante a esta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ideal é não usar nada deste tipo de coisa. Todos são ruins. Mas se quiser insistir e se meter em outro rolo tem algumas alternativas:

- [DevForce](https://www.ideablade.com/store/devforce)
- [XAF](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/application_framework/)
- [PowerApps](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) (não é a mesma coisa, mas pode te ajudar)